# Google Drive Api integration with gmail account

Tags: asp.net, google-drive-api, google-oauth

now I'm trying to do my mvc application which could display data from Google Drive. I want to get google user who is actual logged in browser and display files which are shared with this user with my application. I have already been able to get files and folders info / content from drive but I do it like the owner of driveapikey, not like independant user.
[image: Below I provided schema of desirebale implementation]

For example if user#1 is logged in I could show him only "Files shared with user #1" and "Files shared with everyone". Is it possible to do smth like that?

Comment: yes it's possible. Read the documentation and feel free to post any problems you encounter.

Comment: With regard to sharing files, try to check to [Share Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing). "Every permission of a file or folder has a type. The type is the scope of the permission, and determines which users have a role. Permissions with types user and groups also have an emailAddress. Permissions with type domain have a corresponding domain property that specifies the domain name".

Comment: @pinoyyid 
I went trought steps on https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/people site and now I can get logged in users account info. As I mentioned earlier I have application which uses Google Drive API. How can I obtain only shared with logged user files from my application?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters sharedWithMe

Comment: @pinoyyid Thanks for pointed to that option. Previously I have      request.Q = $"'{directoryId}' in parents"; and it worked fine. Now when I've added request.Q = $"'{directoryId}' in parents and sharedWithMe" drive returns empty file collection. But if I use only request.Q = "sharedWIthMe"  drive returns all shared-with-me file (but I need data only from directoryId). Do you know what can be the problem?

Comment: check the parents field of the files returned by your second attempt and confirm you're using the correct fileId

Comment: When I do with only 'sharedWithMe' option I get response { "id": "somefolderid",   "name": "Root"}. And when I do " 'somefolderid' in parents" it returns all files and folders from somefolderid folder. But when I do " 'somefolderid' in parents and sharedWithMe" it returns empty collection

Comment: It's realy strange because when I do " 'somefolderid' in parents **OR** sharedWithMe" it returns shared-with-me files plus all files from somefolderid